# I have a server that needs to interact with the database frequently. How can I reduce the interaction frequency? Or improve efficiency?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I developed a server-side application with C++ to receive the database request sent by the client. Because the database is large, the client requests much data at one time. I want to know if there is any way to reduce the number of interactions between the server application and the database, or improve the access efficiency.

For example, there are 100 clients requesting data at the same time, and one request includes four types of data. My SQL statements are similar as followings:

```
SELECT x.SourceName, x.Priority, SUM(IIF(NextActive IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) totalCount 
FROM 
(
    SELECT SourceName, Priority, Active, LEAD(Active) OVER(PARTITION BY SourceName ORDER BY TimeStamp) NextActive
    FROM TempTable1
    WHERE SourcePath = 'C:\TempFolder1' and DATEDIFF(week, TimeStamp, GETDATE()) between 0 and 1 
) x
WHERE x.Active = 0 and x.NextActive = 1
GROUP BY x.SourceName, x.Priority
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
```

If the database data is stored locally through SQLite, the above SQL statements cannot be executed and I have to get database data and calculate myself.
Therefore, is there a better method?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: A) Caching. B) Data warehousing as in have a copy of the data to query.

Comment: Use a proper RDBMS, like SQL Server or Postgres

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for your quick answer, but I don't know much about this content. Is there a specific noun or link to learn about it.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your quick answer, but I don't know much about this content. What do you mean by data warehouse? Is that mean the data obtained from the database in the c++ project?

Comment: If you're using SQLite, you can just copy the database over and wreck around with it on whatever workstation/server you're on. If you're dealing with high load, as others point out, it's worth moving to a server-based RDBMS like Postgres that can better handle that kind of activity. SQLIite is a great way to get started, but what it offers in convenience comes at the cost of performance.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the query to work as is, you need a proper RDBMS to be in place. Alternatively, your application could get all records matching the criteria and you can write custom code to programmatically implement the grouping. But it is not a really good approach to invest time into the implementation of features that are already supported by proper RDBMS systems.

The implementation would look like executing the equivalent of your subquery and then loop the results, apply the grouping and the sort. If you do this custom implementation, then you can easily include the outer `WHERE` clause's criteria into your query.

From now on I assume that you either switched to a better RDBMS or implemented this. The next problem is concurrency. You have 100 people requesting similar data at the same time. You will need to cache your data somehow. If your application code already stored the records, then you can apply an app-level cache-system, store the results into temporarily existent files and load the ready-made data from those files while they do not get too old.

Another possible solution is to create a table for the results, whenever a user requests this information, you query this table for data and if none of the data is to be found there, then get it and insert it. This would also involve periodic cleanups.

Finally, since you may have many requests at the same time, it might be a good idea to create a queue of these requests, so you will avoid the multiple creation of the same caches.

Alternatively, you could create a cron job that would periodically calculate these and store the results, independently of whether they are queried or not and only retrieve this ready-made data export whenever a request aims to get this data.